# Solution other than multiple instances of Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver

Im working on an aplication that's supposed to have multiple subdomains for multiple regions with geospatial data to be served saparately for each region. It should be hosted on one server hosting.
Demo of the app is nadlanu.gromatic.hr and opcina.gromatic.hr for other region. 
I'm having problem to separate layer "Komunalni problemi" for the two regions as when the aplication is submitted (rigt menu - "Predaj prijavu") in opcina.gromatic.hr it shows only in nadlanu.gromatic.hr.
I've created separate layer with a different store (with different database) and workspace in Geoserver for that but, obviously, that doesn't work. So, I came to knowledge (correct me if I'm wrong please) that I need multiple instances of geoserver to solve this issue, but that wont work either due to one server hosting limitation, as I need more than 20 separated subdomains with separated geospatial data.

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: sounds like you can handle this with workspaces, virtual endpoints and URL rewrite rules in your web server - there are plenty of [commercial suppliers](http://geoserver.org/support/) who could help with this sort of setup.

Comment: @IanTurton thank you for the comment, but I'm not sure how would I do that, so if you can give me more hints I would appreciate it very much.